# What caused this Ada compilation error "ambiguous character literal"?

Tags: ada, gnat

I have this Ada code.

```
with Ada.Text_IO; 
use Ada.Text_IO;

procedure for_Loop is
begin
    for Counter in 'A'..'Z' loop
        Put(Counter);   
    end loop;
    New_Line;
end for_Loop;
```

The Ada compiler (gnatmake) outputs these error message.

```
gcc -c for_loop.adb
for_loop.adb:6:24: ambiguous character literal
for_loop.adb:6:24: possible interpretation: Character
for_loop.adb:6:24: possible interpretation: Wide_Character
for_loop.adb:6:24: possible interpretation: Wide_Wide_Character
gnatmake: "for_loop.adb" compilation error
```

What's wrong with the code?

Comment: I would say that **what** is wrong with the source text is quite clear from the error message. - An appropriate question could be "How can I avoid that the character literal is ambigous?".  (There are at least three possible answers to that question. :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [this post](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gnat_rm/Legal-Ada-83-programs-that-are-illegal-in-Ada-95.html):

> The problem is that 'A' and 'Z' could be from either Character or Wide_Character. The simplest correction is to make the type explicit; e.g.: for Char in Character range 'A' .. 'Z' loop ... end loop;

```
with Ada.Text_IO; 
use Ada.Text_IO;

procedure for_Loop is
begin
    for Counter in Character range 'A'..'Z' loop
        Put(Counter);   
    end loop;
    New_Line;
end for_Loop;
```

This is the oupput:

```
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
```

Comment: That doesn't explain *why* it's invalid. The link does, but the information should be in the answer.