# How to unambiguously specify a character literal

Tags: ada

As I've been working through "Rendezvous with Ada 95", I've run into what seems like a common Ada83 / Ada95 incompatibility: the dreaded `ambiguous character literal` error in the line:

```
Put ( Disk < Screen and 'P' < 'B' );
```

I'm new to Ada but not to strongly-typed languages and I understand the issue: there's no way to determine if a literal is of type `Character` or of `Wide_Character` and that ambiguity results in a compile-time error.

My question is, how would one change the statement above to specify a character literal with a given type (*e.g.* as a `Character` or `Wide_Character`)? I've read over similar questions ([What caused this Ada compilation error "ambiguous character literal"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29934365/what-caused-this-ada-compilation-error-ambiguous-character-literal)) and they don't provide any guidance beyond RTFM. Other references (https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gnat_rm/Legal-Ada-83-programs-that-are-illegal-in-Ada-95.html) show workarounds for character ranges but not for single literals.

In a different language, I'd expect to cast the literals to a given type but my impression of Ada is that weaseling around type-checking would (should?) be discouraged. I know I could just explicitly define the literals as constants of a given type but that seems to defeat the purpose of allowing literals in the body of the code.

I imagine this is a very common issue when modernizing Ada83 code; what is the best practice for disambiguating ambiguous character literals inline?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use  a [*qualified expression*](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-4-7.html) to identify the type explicitly:

```
Put ( Disk < Screen and Character'('P') < Character'('B') );
```

Comment: Thank you! A friend had also suggested using `To_Character` from `Ada.Characters.Handling` but your answer seems to match the intent much better (specifying a thing of a particular type and value versus using a function call to return a thing of a particular type).

Comment: @arclight: Likewise, `Ada.Characters.Handling` became [_obsolescent_](http://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/05rat/html/Rat-7-5.html#I1339) in Ada 2005; it was supplanted by `Ada.Characters.Conversions`.

Comment: @trashgod - not all of Ada.Characters.Handling has been banished. Only the functions "from Is_Character to To_Wide_String in Ada.Characters.Handling have been banished to Annex J."

Comment: You only really need to qualify one of the literals, unless you have a "<" visible that takes a Character and another character type. Anything that defines the type of one of them will work, such as: `P : constant Character := 'P'; ... P < 'B'`